# Grep from bash return No such file or directory but work if the same command executed manually from CLI

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, grep

If i execute below bash script named `test.sh`, I receive this error:

```
./test.sh: line 8: grep -irl -e"1234567891" ./save: No such file or directory
```

If I execute the line above taken from error "manually" from CLI, it works as expected and finds a single file containing the requested pattern.

```
#!/bin/bash

list="text_list.txt"
ddt_folder1="Save/"

while IFS= read -r line
do
  test=$("grep -irl -e\"$line\" ./save")
  echo "$test"
done < "$list"
```

Tested so far:

echoing "pwd" on top before loop and the path is the right one where the save folder is

```
echo $("pwd")
```

I also tested with full path for destination directory:

```
test=$("grep -irl -e\"$line\" ./full/path/save")
```

also tested with full grep path:

```
test=$("/usr/bin/grep -irl -e\"$line\" ./full/path/save")
```

tested the grep type for full path:

```
type /usr/bin/grep
/usr/bin/grep is /usr/bin/grep
```

Anyway, in all tests if I use the command shown on the error message "manually" from cli, it's work.

what I'm missing!?

thank you very much

Comment: why are you using a shell while read loop here?  Use `grep`'s `-f` option instead. e.g. just `test=$(grep -f "$list" ./save)`

Comment: This is an extract of a more complex script, the source list is dynamically created from and external process and the $test is used with some other rules to create a special output.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you're using a woefully inefficient and slow while-read loop instead of grep's `-f` option.  Your while-read loop does what `-f` does but badly and slowly.  It runs `grep` once per line in "$list" and, worse, recurses through all the files & dirs in ./save each time it runs grep.   whereas with grep -f, grep would only run once and only recurse through ./save once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here

> ```
> test=$("grep -irl -e\"$line\" ./save")
> ```

You have quoted the text inside the `$( ... )` evaluation brackets, so the shell cannot split it into words.  The result is that it's trying to execute a command called `save` in the directory `grep -irl -e"1234567891" .` where `1234567891` is the value of `$line`. (Yes, that can be a real file/directory name; try `touch 'grep -irl -e"1234567891" .'` and then `ls`) Obviously, regardless of the value for `$line`, which is interpolated into the string, that's not going to exist.

Use this instead

```
test=$(grep -irl -e "$line" ./save)
```

By the way, `echo $("pwd")` is equally incorrect and should be `echo "$(pwd)"`. But this could fail if you were in a directory whose name started with a dash (eg `-work`), so it could more easily and correctly be written simply as `pwd`.

Finally, to remove the file name starting with `grep` that you might have created earlier on with `touch`, use `rm -i ./grep*` and enter `y` to confirm the delete.